# Implementation file unable to identify class name from C++ Header file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am learning C++. I am practising splitting my C++ class into separate files- implementation and header files namely **Student_Impl.cpp** and **Student_Header.h**. And then there is a driver file **Student_register.cpp** which will create 3 Student objects. However, when I try to build it, it's throwing errors stating Student is not a namespace or class. I have included the Student_Header.h (where Student class declaration is present) in my implementation file Student_Impl.cpp and driver file Student_register.cpp but it still throwing the same errors. What can be the possible cause ? I am using Visual Studio 2015.

**Student_Header.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student {
private:
    string fname;
    string lname;
    string address;
    string city;
    string phone;
    int age;

public:
    Student();
    Student(string, string, string, string, string, int);
    ~Student();
    string get_fname();
    string get_lname();
    string get_address();
    string get_city();
    string get_phone();
    int get_age();
};
```

**Student_Impl.cpp**

```
    #include "Student_Header.h"
    #include "iostream"
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    Student::Student()
    {

    }

    Student::Student(string fname1, string lname1, string address1, string city1, string phone1, int age1)
    {
        fname = fname1;
        lname = lname1;
        address = address1;
        city = city1;
        phone = phone1;
        age = age1;
    }

    string Student::get_fname()
    {
        return fname;
    }

    string Student::get_lname()
    {
        return lname;
    }

    string Student::get_address()
    {
        return address;
    }

    string Student::get_city()
    {
        return city;
    }

    string Student::get_phone()
    {
        return phone;
    }

    int Student::get_age()
    {
        return age;
    }


    Student::~Student()
    {}
```

**Student_register.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Student_Header.h"
#include <string>
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Student Student1("Mike", "J", "MikeAdd", "MikeCity", "MikePhone", 26);
    Student Student2("Jack", "R", "JackAdd", "JackCity", "JackPhone", 25);
    Student Student3("Roney", "M", "RoneyAdd", "RoneyCity", "RoneyPhone", 27);

    // code for data retrieval

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the correct header file included?
If you have more than one file with the same name in different folders, the compiler might pick the wrong one.
To find out which file is actually used, you can enable the "Show Includes" option for one of the implementation files. This option used to be in the "C++" - "Advanced" section of the file properties IIRC.

Comment: @MarvinSielenkemper Yes, Student_Header.h is correct header file. It's the only file with that name.

Comment: You should include your local header files _after_ "stdafx.h" in "Student_Impl.cpp". That file is part of the precompiled header mechanism of the VS and needs some extra care.

Comment: @MarvinSielenkemper Thanks alot. It worked :) . It would have taken me days  to figure that out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It might actually be a good idea to disable precompiled headers for your project since that should just be an optimization used in huge projects but for some reason has made it into the project template.

Comment: Thanks @MarvinSielenkemper. I will go through that.

Answer (score 0):

Marvin Sielenkemper  put the correct answer in the comment - headers *prior* to "stdafx.h" are ignored. This is an implementation-specific side effect of how precompiled headers work on Visual Studio.

Also, use `#include <iostream>` instead of `#include "iostream"`. The `<header>` form is for standard headers, the `"header.h"` is for your own headers.